# Getting json response from servlet and display in jsp table?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a servlet to get list of objects from database and the list am returning as json from the servlet. Same json response will be displayed in jsp table as below.

Servlet code:

```
        String json = new Gson().toJson(resultList); 
        response.setContentType("application/json"); //here i have the data and i came to know by debugging 
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./dataFetchController",
    success: function(responseJson) {

console.log(responseJson); //it is not printing any result on firebug console

        var master = $(this).parents("table.myTable");

        $.each(responseJson, function(index, contact) {    // Iterate over the JSON array.
            // Get a new row based on the prototype row
            var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
            prot.attr("class", "");
            prot.find("#myName").attr("value", contact.name);
            prot.find("#myLastName").attr("value", contact.lastName);

            //master.find("tbody").append(prot);
            jQuery('table.myTable tr:last').before(prot);
        });
    },
    error: function(ob,errStr) {
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('<img src="./public/images/error.png" /> <span style="color:red">Save is not successful. Try Again.</span>');
    }
});
```

I am not getting any json result. I tried printing it using console but no result but in servlet it has data returned from database and verified using debug. Am i missing anything here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that it is entering the `success` block?

Comment: yes..it is entering success block..i verified by keeping an alert. but data is not coming..

Comment: @Gaara,  is there any other way to get list of objects from servlets to as a response to ajax call?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Simply try and paste the REST URL on your browser. Since it is a GET request, if anything is returning from the server, it'll print it on the browser window.

Comment: @Gaara, i tried pasting the url on browser and is printing the response properly..

Comment: Then the possible reason is that the URL that you are passing for the AJAX call might be malformed.

Comment: But am getting results till servlet. if it is malformed it should not call the controller itself right? Please help me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35058/discussion-between-kazekage-gaara-and-user1016403)

Answer (score 0):

I could not see "dataType" in Your Ajax request like:

dataType: 'json'

try adding it.

so, it will become:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "./dataFetchController",
 success: function(responseJson) {
       //alert and success handler
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 error : function(){
   // error handler
 });
```

dataType is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server